# Too many values to unpack (expected 2) in Python while using dictionary function

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, input

I have a problem in python , I am getting an error meassage

```
ValueError-:Too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Where as when i am inputing less than 4 char in a dictionary key there is an another error

```
ValueError-:Not enough value to unpack (expected 2,got2).
```

Program Description : I am a newbie programmer i just started my python and i thought to create a dictionary with user input, then i started from inputing the data using for loop and then print them in a for loop condition . My programm run sucessfully without any error but when its time to print the dictionary its shows the type error.

code:

```
for word, mean in d:
    print(word, "<------>", mean)
```

Comment: Try `for word, mean in d.items(): print(word, "<------>", mean)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough, but I think this is what's missing :

The items in `d` should be presented as a sequence of two values (like `[('aa', 3), ('bb', 4), ...]`. to be able to get assign it to a the tuple `word, mean` which is composed of 2 elements.

and when using a `dict` the method `items()` returns something similar to what you need which is of type `dict_items()`.

```
for word, mean in d.items() : 
    print(word, "<------>", mean)
```